# Add new tab to Account's activity

Tags: lightning-experience, custom-object, activities

When clicking on an account, the client has an activity tab on the right side of the page. The activity currently has 2 tabs under it. One is for  New Task and another for Email. The client wants to add a third tab under the account activity. What is the right way to create tab under account activity? Please note this is not opportunity activity. It is account activity.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That part of the layout is governed by quick actions (which are a subset of global actions) and you can customise them based on 'Salesforce Mobile and lightning Experience Actions' in the Page Layout for the Account Object.

NB: Before adding the Quick Action, you'll need to set it up under 'Global Actions' in the main Setup menu.

There's a bit more info here: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/lex_migration_customization/lex_migration_customization_actions