# How to rename "Log a Call" to something like "Notes"

Tags: lightning, log-a-call

Seems like such a simple task but I cannot figure out how to just rename the Log a Call tab on the contact lightning page to Notes.

Any insight into how to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

As it is a standard Action we cannot rename it. But you can create an action of type "log a call " and add all the fields required and add that to the pagelayout and remove log a call from it.

Please find the below [link](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/252775/add-new-tab-to-accounts-activity) on how to add custom action on activity bar